# Moving from packaging to platform-development tags

Tags: discussion, tags

One of the coolest integration stories we have is the tie in between Ask Ubuntu and [developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com), which enabled us to build a pretty impressive library of q+a for application developers. You can find all of this in [application-development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application-development).

Jokerdino reached out to some people another area of ubuntu development, which is development of ubuntu itself. Traditionally in the project this has been called "Ubuntu Development", but it tends to be confusing to people because for some that is packaging, for some it's fixing bugs, and so on.

David Planella recommended to me that we should start off with [platform-development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/platform-development) and symlink [packaging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packaging) to that, and maybe other tags (perhaps [patch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/patch) or whatever other thing relates to fixing ubuntu itself.

That way we have one tag for people who want to ask questions about developing ON ubuntu, and one tag for people who want to develop Ubuntu itself and it would give Ubuntu developers one tag to subscribe to to answer Q+A about working on Ubuntu.

Why symlink [packaging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packaging) to [platform-development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/platform-development)? Well, the experts in packaging in Ubuntu are MOTU/ubuntu developers/debian developers. I want to have one tag where they can subscribe to. Sure there will be some questions where someone will want to package something that won't want to contribute that to the community, but having one tag that I can tell them to subscribe to outweighs the semantic details of people's intent.

Thoughts?

Comment: +1 I agree with you, but why packaging symlink with platform development?

Comment: @tachyons See my edit, I hope that answers the question!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about this. I'm subscribed to and I am the top answerer in the [packaging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/packaging) tag.  The majority of questions I see there are not actually related to Ubuntu platform development. They are app developers looking to package their app for Ubuntu users, sysadmins looking to package their scripts for deployment, and folks packaging things for PPAs. While I hope to attract these kinds of people to Ubuntu development, for the most part the tag hasn't been about that explicitly.

Another issue with a [platform-development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/platform-development) tag is that it is not a particularly well-known or understood term. I don't expect that anyone not already involved with Ubuntu development would ever imagine to tag their questions with that. To most people, that tag wouldn't suggest packaging or Ubuntu development. I expect that to most people it suggest something along the lines of developing their own derivative.